# How do I restore an album that Apple Photos deleted by itself?

Tags: icloud, photos.app

I use Apple Photos, with iCloud Photo Library, and I created an album, but after a while I noticed that the album disappeared. I never deleted it. The album is called "Nexus vs iPhone", and it no longer appears in the sidebar:

[image]

I checked on two Macs, and on iPhone, and it appears nowhere. I also checked on iCloud.com, and it doesn't show there, either.

How do I get it back? Recently Deleted shows photos, not albums, and View > Show Hidden Photo Album does nothing.

The only thing that happened in the couple of weeks before I noticed that the album disappeared is that I signed out of iCloud on my iPhone, and then signed in.

Comment: Did you create the album on your iPhone? I suspect the album was not synced with iCloud, and signing out and in overwrote it.

Comment: I created the album on the Mac. It was synced, and showing on both my Mac and iPhone. Later, when I signed out of iCloud on my iPhone, it deleted them everywhere.

Comment: Then I'd guess your only option would be get it back from Time Machine

Comment: I don't use Time Machine. It seems that I've lost my album permanently.